# Can't add Items to spinner

Tags: java, android, dialog, spinner

I am having trouble adding items to my spinner from an Arraylist. I have it working in other parts of my code, but it wont work when I put it in my dialog.
The exact problem is that it causes the app to crash. The crash happens when I press the button to open the dialog.

Here is the problematic code:

```
public void transferButton(View view) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_transfer);

    ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList();
    List<String> accounts = new ArrayList();

    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myExternalFile = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + folderLoc, "accounts.txt");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            file.add(strLine);
        }
        br.close();
        in.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner fromSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.fromAccountSpinner);
    Spinner toSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.toAccountSpinner);


    for (int i = 0; i < file.size(); i++) {
        String[] splitArray = file.get(i).split("//");
        adapter1.add(splitArray[0]);
        adapter2.add(splitArray[0]);
    }

    adapter1.insert("From...", 0);
    fromSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

    adapter2.insert("To...", 0);
    toSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gstraatsma.gsfinancetracker, PID: 14493
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.gstraatsma.gsfinancetracker.MainActivity.transferButton(MainActivity.java:1258)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6205) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11103) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23653) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Might require to first learn how to figure where and how android logs errors...

Comment: I have adder the crash log

Comment: One or both of your Spinners are null.

Comment: What do you mean by that, they are both in the layout xml, and Android Studio shows no errors in the code @TheWanderer

Comment: But they're not a child of the `view` that's passed to your method I bet.

Comment: you don't have `fromAccountSpinner` or `toAccountSpinner` in the view that you are passing into your method.

Comment: One of the spinners is null...  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
  `

Answer (score 0):

Change `view.findViewById(R.id.fromAccountSpinner);` to `dialog.findViewById(R.id.fromAccountSpinner);`